# How to print sqlplus output immediate

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have very simple pl\sql code.

In this code I'm printing the index of the loop and wait 1 second before each print.

My problem is that I want this output to be used like a live log, when the dbms_output.put_line procedure is invoked and print - I want to see the output immediately.

In the current code - only after it finished (5 seconds..), it prints all the output in one shot...

```
set serveroutput on
set echo on

begin

for i in 1..5
loop
dba_maint.pkg_utils.sp_sleep(1);
dbms_output.put_line(i);
end loop;

end;
/
```

Comment: @Littlefoot is correct; your dbms_ouput is displayed only after the procedure completes. The reason for this is that the procedure, through the database manager does, not actually produce the displayed output. The database manager actually just writes to an internal in-memory buffer. Once the procedure completes that buffer is read by your client process (SQLplus, an IDE,...) and that process creates your displayed output. Direct output across 100s of clients would just be way **way** too slow.

Answer (score 2):

No way, you can't. It is displayed when PL/SQL procedure has finished.

If you want to create a *live log*,

- create a table
- a sequence
- an autonomous transaction procedure which would

  - insert a row into that table
  - using a sequence (so that you'd know how to order rows)
  - possibly a timestamp (so that you'd know how long certain step took)
  - commit (which won't affect main transaction as - remember - procedure is an *autonomous* transaction one)

Then put calls to the *logging* procedure into your long-time-run PL/SQL procedure, run it, and let it work. In another session, query the log table to view progress.